# Reverse Proxy Apache

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, proxy, centos, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse proxy for apache, centos.I keep getting a redirect error.
Essentially what I want to do is make it so that I do not have to access my springboot from `https://example.com:8443/login` and instead from `https://example.com/login`, or to at least forward anyone that goes to the first to the former. Below is my configuration file for the virtual host.

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
 SSLProxyEngine on
  ProxyPass / https://example.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://example.com:8443/
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
  ProxyPreserveHost On

SSLEngine on
  SSLProxyEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/path/example.com/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/path/example.com/privkey.pem

 # Allow from anywhere
    <Directory />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```